# How do I require gems?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I'm writing a pure Ruby script, not Rails.

This script is trivial:

```
require 'progressbar'

bar = ProgressBar.new("Example progress", 50)
total = 0
until total >= 50
  sleep(rand(2)/2.0)
  increment = (rand(6) + 3)
  bar.inc(increment)
  total += increment
end
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
./progressbar.rb:3: uninitialized constant ProgressBar (NameError)
from progressbar.rb:1:in `require'
from progressbar.rb:1
```

The gem is installed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `gem list progressbar` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on Ruby 1.8, I would rename the file you've in the question from `progressbar.rb` to `pg_test.rb` or anything other than `progressbar.rb`.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'progressbar'

bar = ProgressBar.new("Example progress", 50)
total = 0
until total >= 50
  sleep(rand(2)/2.0)
  increment = (rand(6) + 3)
  bar.inc(increment)
  total += increment
end
```

In the shell:

```
$ ruby ./pg_test.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the backtrace, I think ruby is actually trying to load your progressbar.rb rather than the one from the gem.

Prior to 1.9 you should also do `require 'rubygems'` so that the rubygems library itself is loaded

Comment: When I add `require 'rubygems'` to the top, it still throws a uninitialized constant ProgressBar (NameError). When I switch to Ruby 1.9.2, it all runs fine. I guess I should just stick to writing scripts in 1.9.2?

Comment: @LeonardTeo, going with 1.9.x is probably the best option, but it's always good to have scripts run in both environments. Are you sure you have installed the gem for both versions of ruby?

Comment: @harald. Absolutely sure. gem list progressbar shows it on both versions of ruby. I'm using rvm to switch between ruby versions. Just curious how come something as simple as require 'gemname' doesn't work on 1.8.7....

Comment: @Leonard Teo: As others have indicated, the file with your code is called progressbar.rb. The actual code for the progressbar gem is in another file, somewhere else, also called progressbar.rb . => conflict. Rename the file with your code. Everyone makes this mistake at least once.

Comment: @LeonardTeo, as both Frederick and I pointed out, in 1.8.x require first looks in the current directory, there it finds a file that matches (your script) and tries to load it. This does not resolve the symbol, so you get an error. By renaming the file, it should work also in 1.8.7.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Ruby 1.8.x, try to rename your source file to `progressbar_test.rb` and run it instead. Chances are that's all there's to it, since your require statement tries to load your own sourcefile instead of the one in the gem.

Comment: This could happen with Ruby 1.8, but not in 1.9, because `require` no longer searches '.'

Comment: @thetinman: it wouldn't happen in 1.9.2 but it would in 1.9.1 .

Comment: Yes, true, 1.9.2 was the changing point. 1.9.1 didn't have a lot of adopters because of some bugs, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

[Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) is by far the best solution for managing dependencies in ruby apps.

```
$ gem install bundler
$ bundle gem <gem-name>
```

You'll get the standard file structure for a ruby gem library that looks like this:

```
my_awesome_gem
  Gemfile
  my_awesome_gem.gemspec
  Rakefile
  lib
    my_awesome_gem.rb
    my_awesome_gem
      version.rb
```

Open up your Gemfile and add your dependencies like this

`gem 'progressbar'`

Then in lib/my_awesome_gem.rb do this:

```
require 'bundler/setup' #initialize bundler, which works its magic on your load path
require 'progressbar' #require whatever gems (make sure they're listed in your Gemfile)

bar = ProgressBar.new("Example progress", 50)
total = 0
until total >= 50
  sleep(rand(2)/2.0)
  increment = (rand(6) + 3)
  bar.inc(increment)
  total += increment
end
```

Finally, to run your script:

`$ ruby lib/my_awesome_gem.rb`

Bunder is definitely the best way to do this.  You won't have issues with the differences in ruby versions and you know your script will fit in with the standards and best practices of the ruby community.  I highly recommend using bundler from the beginning.  This also helps when you start adding test because you're already setup to start `require`ing any of the gems you've listed as dependencies in your tests as well.

Plus, if your script gets to the point that you'd like to distribute it, it's already set up to publish to rubygems.org.

Check out [this blog post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/02/using-gemspecs-as-intended/) by yehuda katz for more on that.

Comment: For a simple test application like this, bundler is major overkill. For a production app it is a very good solution.